# pub build to subdirectory?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Is it possible to build to a subdirectory within `build` ? So that everything that's linked in the Dart application code looks for the assets in a sub directory prefix?

Essentially I'm trying to combine two Dart apps... So assets in `web` are conflicting. Of course the symlinks in `web/packages` are different and/or could conflict as well.

I want to take the HTML code from the one main `index.html` and put it into the other application - that part fits together fine without conflict. I also want to then link the other dart2js compiled main.dart.js file... Again both Dart apps run without conflict side by side... But I run into issues with all the assets.

I'm also using angular.dart for this second project where the first is not. Due to that, it's not just as simple as changing a few `<img src="img/example.jpg" />` to `<img src="symlinked-path/img/example.jpg" />` ... I have within the Dart application various references to assets like HTML template partials, etc.

It's almost like as if I need some sort of `<base>` tag for just the parts I'm after. It unfortunately doesn't work that way, but that's kinda the best way I can describe what I'm after if it doesn't make sense yet.

So I was hoping that `pub build` had some options or perhaps even the transformer could output everything and have dart2js change things in the JS to point to some subdirectory under build. I could then symlink that.

Thoughts about merging two Dart apps?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I read: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/assets-and-transformers.html#where-to-put-assets

Was a little confusing but I got it and think it'll work for my situation... I put a new `asset` directory alongside at the same level as my `web` directory and then `pub build` moved those files into a `assets/my_package_name` directory... Which I can symlink without conflict. So now nothing is in `web` other than my `index.html` file which I'm yanking the guts out of anyway.

Comment: Though you need to use `pub serve` to test which takes forever. I like loading the HTML file that includes the `main.dart` file in there for development (it's faster, no building required). So that stinks.

Comment: The assets directory is deprecated. Assets should go into lib or web directory. But you should be able to solve it with a similar approach.

Comment: That's a shame because it does exactly what I want. Should also be removed from the dart site documentation I guess too. ...I hope there's something to replace it too. Dart package managent leaves a lot to be desired.

Comment: You can use any directory inside the lib directory. Assets in a lib subdirectory should be handled like in the deprecated assets directory.

Comment: Yea, that'll work. Thanks. I guess (and this is true even of the old `asset` directory) the only thing is when opening up an HTML file from `web` that you want to keep refreshing while you develop, your assets can't easily be linked.

Comment: For example - when opening up an HTML file from `web` that you want to keep refreshing while you develop, your assets can't easily be linked. Your path changes from "lib/assets/whatever" to "packages/package_name/assets/whatever" in the final `build` directory. So if your HTML file pathed a stylesheet, it could only be used it after a long build process. Slowing down development.

Comment: oooh n/m it symlinks it =) yay